# jdk1.6 JMAP.EXE: Remote thread failed for unknown reason 

Tags: java, jvm-crash, jmap

I get this error when using the following batch file to take a core dump of a Java service running in a Windows console shell:

```
The parent directory name of this script is: MyDIR
Install dir is: C::\InstallDIR    
The process id of window called MyDIR is 520
Taking core dump... please wait...
C::\InstallDIR\Javasoft\bin\jmap.exe -dump:file=heap.bin 520
Dumping heap to C:\InstallDIR\MyDIR\heap.bin ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Remote thread failed for 
  unknown reason
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.enqueue(Native Method)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.execute(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:78)
        at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:195)
        at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.dumpHeap(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:162)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.dump(JMap.java:224)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:122)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And here is the script (-XX:OnError="script.bat") :

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\InstallDIR\Javasoft\jre\bin\server
for /F "tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=\" %%i in ('cd') do (
  set i=%%i
  set j=%%j
  set k=%%k
  set l=%%l
  set m=%%m
  set n=%%n
)
set HOME=%i%
if not "%i%" == "" (set SITE=%i%
) else (goto end:)
if not "%j%" == "" (set SITE=%j%
) else (goto end:)
if not "%k%" == "" (set SITE=%k%
) else (goto end:)
if not "%l%" == "" (set SITE=%l%
) else (goto end:)
if not "%m%" == "" (set SITE=%m%
) else (goto end:)
if not "%n%" == "" (set SITE=%n%
) else (goto end:)
:end
echo The parent directory name of this script is: %SITE%
echo Install dir is: %HOMEDRIVE%:\%HOME%
echo.

:: kill process using window TITLE to find PID
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('TASKLIST /NH /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %SITE%"' ) DO SET PID=%%I
ECHO The process id of window called %SITE% is %PID%
ECHO Taking core dump... please wait...
%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOME%\Javasoft\bin\jmap.exe -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin %PID%
ECHO Killing JVM %PID%...
TASKKILL /PID %PID%
:: then , restart server
.\startServer.bat    
ping -n 12 127.0.0.1>nul
if ERRORLEVEL == 0 (
  exit
) else (
  pause
)
```

I can run jconsole.exe , attach to the process and dump the core easily.  Why isn't this as easy from the command line?  I know that the linux version of JMap has more options and capabilities.  Is this what I am running into here: a situation where the windows version of JMap just isn't able to do this simple thing?

Comment: Does your script have the same credentials as the java process?

Comment: Yes, its ran by the same user.  It's windows xp, so the permissions aren't as strict in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

The -XX:OnError handler is called for *fatal* jvm errors. when that happens you probably won't be able to start a new thread to dump the heap. (That's what jmap does.)

However, you can probably accomplish what you want by passing
**-X:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError** and 
**-XX:HeapDumpPath=*path***.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question about why JMap failed.    Also, the batch file is meant to be able to close the console and recover it by starting the JVM back up.  So, if I have a fatal error, I want to be able to kill the process and restart the JVM.

Comment: Killing the process should still work. The issue with JMap is that it works by injecting a thread into the JVM and capturing the heap from the inside. If the JVM is in an out of memory state, or the internal logic is otherwise compromised, it may not possible to start a new thread. You should be able to combine the options above with the -XX:OnError and have the script restart the process.

Comment: In this case I am running my script against a healthy server JVM. So, in theory, JMap.exe shouldn't have had a problem injected the heapdump message. I want to focus on Jmap for now rather than on -XX arguments to the VM. (see my original question)

Comment: I tried with and without the debug flags.  In theory, all JMap.exe needs is the process ID right?  It isn't connecting with RMI nor with JMX right?

Comment: I traced jmap as far as a call to windows CreateRemoteThread at which it asks the windows runtime to create a new thread in the target JVM. I'm guessing that's where it's failing. The page on CreateRemoteThread may offer something: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx